# Android CoordinatorLayout - Inconsistencies between Android versions

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-tablayout

I used Android support design library to build a profile view for an app I'm working on.

The profile is composed of a header with a header picture as the background and a rounded profile picture on the center. Besides, there ir a small view on the bottom corner of the header.

Below the header is a viewpager with a tablayout.

The problem I'm facing is that there are inconsistencies between Android 5.1.1 and 5.0.2 and below.

Here's how the profile is shown on a Nexus 5 with 5.1.1 Android:
[image: No TabLayout shown here]

And here's how the profile is shown on a Xperia Z2 with 5.0.2 Android:
[image: The header does not show views inside CollapsingToolbarLayout]

Here's the code:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@color/white">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_collapsingtoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

            <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                app:riv_corner_radius="45dp"
                app:riv_border_color="@color/red"
                app:riv_border_width="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_usertype_background">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="Professional"/>
            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/profile_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/profile_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:paddingTop="45dp"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/red"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/main_dark"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/red"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/profile_floatingbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/red"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/profile_pager"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

So, anyone has an idea on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't resolve your issue, but why you are using a FrameLayout as root ? it is not needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Design Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) is unfortunately quite buggy and it should be considered "beta" rather than production ready. It looks and behaves differently depending on Android version your app is running on and problems I spotted are not only related to `CoordinatorLayout`, but even relatively simple widget like `TextInputLayout` is not working the same way everywhere. Knowing design library is quite fresh product, I am not sure it is worth spending your own time **working around** (not fixing) Google bugs. I'd just wait for next iteration of the library, expecting improvements and bug fixes.

Comment: Do you know when the next version will be out?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I can wait so 4-6 weeks is fine with me. If that's ok with you then wait, if not, it may be less problematic to drop design library and replace its widgets/functions with other libs. Or live with the issues if possible for a moment. It's up to you at that stage